# For loop does not stop

Tags: python, pandas

```
for lat,lng,value in zip(location_saopaulo_df['geolocation_lat'], location_saopaulo_df['geolocation_lng'], location_saopaulo_df['municipality']):
    coordinates = (lat,lng)
    items = rg.search(coordinates)
    value = items[0]['admin2']
```

I am trying to iterate over 3 columns from the dataframe, get the latitude and longitude values from the two columns, use it to get the address then add the city name to the last column I stated which is an empty column consists of NaN values.

However, my for loop is not stopping. I would be grateful if you can tell me why it doesn't stop or better way to do what I'm trying to do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That loop should terminate unless `location_saopaulo_df['geolocation_lat']` and such are infinite. Are you sure it's just not taking a long time printing a ton of data?

Comment: Before the loop, print the length, of one column. Then use an index inside the loop and print it each 1000, `if index%1000==0 : print(index)` (1000 is just an example) to follow

Comment: can you test it on much smaller dataframe? this loop is not the infinite one :)

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I'm not sure what was exactly causing the problem but I think it's because of the size of the dataset since Jupyter is crashing when I'm trying to for loop to add popups in the map with the same size of the dataset after taking a long time iterating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `rg` is `reverse_geocoder`, there is a better way to [query several coordinates](https://github.com/thampiman/reverse-geocoder#usage) at once than looping. try this:

```
res =  rg.search(tuple(zip(location_saopaulo_df['geolocation_lat'], 
                           location_saopaulo_df['geolocation_lng'])))
```

And then extract just the admin2 value by constructing  dataframe for example like:

```
df_ = pd.Dataframe(res)
```

and see what it looks like. You may be able to perform a merge or index alignment to put it back into your original dataframe `location_saopaulo_df`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Would you explain how this could return the entire values at once if you don't mind and do you know why my for loop did not stop iterating by any chance?

Comment: @yasitski as written in the link provided in the answer, the library has this possibility but I'm not sure how it is implemented in it. For your loop for, I don't think it did not stop iterating, it was just really long to do. The problem is more that you tried to do 100 (length of your dataframe) times the `search`. But let's say the `search` takes 1 second to perform (fake number, just to explain the idea), but over the 1 second, 0.99s is used to preprocess the input and process the output, only 0.01 s is used for matching long-lat. so overall 100s

Comment: @yasitski Now when you pass n couples long-lat at once, the preprocessing and output formatting will still be about 0.99s because it is probably vectorized in the library code, and matching 100 long-lat will be overall 100*0.01s so 1s. so you ends up of an overall time of 2s instead of 100s. hope it helps to understand